# Unity / gnome-terminal passing control keys

Tags: command-line, unity, emacs, gnu-screen

I'm trying to get a setup with GNU screen in gnome terminal that I'm happy with (emacs user). I really like having <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> as my GNU screen command key (as it doesn't interfere with any emacs key bindings http://emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuScreen).

This key combination works fine when I ssh into my Ubuntu box, but not directly in gnome-terminal or logging directly into console. Input of press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> seems to be completely ignored by both.

Any ideas on how to fix this or things that'd help diagnose/fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
stty -a # gnome-terminal settings
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
 opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
 isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop - echoprt
 echoctl echoke
```

Comment: how have you set ctr-^ to be your shortcut, or was it set by default?

Comment: Thanks, good point. I start screen with the following alias `screen -e ^^^^ -d -R` .

Answer (score 1):

Doh! There's a `.screenrc` on this system that is overriding command-line arguments. Problem solved.